# play 2.3.8(activator)からのjvm-debugについて

Tags: scala, playframework

Windows7上でplay 2.3.8とEclipseのScalaIDEの環境で開発しています。

以前はうまく動作していたコマンドが動作しなくなったのですが、原因や調査方法に
心当たりある方がいましたらご教示ください。

- 事象
  `activator -jvm-debug 9999 run` でプロジェクトが起動できなくなった。
  以前だと `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999` というメッセージの後に
  リッスンまで稼働していたと思うのですが、原因不明ですが↑のメッセージで止まってしまい、
  それ以上動作しなくなってしまいました。
  プロジェクトを新規作成してそちらで同じコマンドを叩いても変わらなかったので、ソースや
  ライブラリ依存性ではないと思っています。

runで実行するとアプリ自体は稼働しますが、debugでブレークポイントを仕掛けられないので
詳細の確認が難しい状況になっています。

やりたいこととしてはEclipseでのデバッグのステップ操作なので、もし対処法をご存知の方が
いましたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: target/ フォルダの下を全部一旦削除して、`activator -jvm-debug 9999 run` を実行するとどんな結果でしょうか？

Comment: @turutosiya さん  
target/以下を削除して試しても変わらず固まってしまいます。  
他にもJavaを再インストールしたり最新バージョンに変更してもダメでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すみません、自己解決できました。

動かなかった原因がactivatorのバージョンが悪かったみたいで、activatorの1.2.2だとjvm-debugがうまく行かないようで、1.3.2に変更したらうまくいくようになりました。
どこかで過去に使っていたバージョンが混ざりこんでバージョンが変わったみたいです。
お騒がせしました。